# Position element relative to cursor using purely CSS3

Tags: css, hover, sass

How can I position an element--such as a complex cursor unsuitable for the `cursor` property--relative to the mouse position using CSS 3?

I know how to do this with JavaScript, but it appears too choppy; I'd rather use CSS and fall back to jQuery when support is lacking.  (Event when I work with elements directly and bypass jQuery, it's too slow.)

JavaScript can be used to make preparations and such, if necessary.  While not preferable on principal, JavaScript is acceptable as long as it isn't in charge of updating the element every time the mouse moves.

I kindly request that answers not be used to reason why this cannot be achieved, as CSS is rapidly evolving, and the future potential of solving this problem may change.  Feel free to speculate all you want in comments.

I am using Sass (SCSS) with Compass and jQuery, along with my own JavaScript framework.

Comment: Are you looking for drag+drop functionality or something else? D+D is part of the HTML5 spec and should be fairly easy to get working. It will need some JS, but shouldn't be 'choppy'. In any case, even in the absense of native D+D, what you're asking for ought to be possible without being 'choppy'; if it is choppy, you should maybe consider doing some performance analysis of your JS code. The odds are you've got events that are being fired repeatedly as you move the mouse which are trying to do too much work.

Comment: I'm using this to have a loading icon follow the cursor during an ajax request.  Per design specifications, it has to be separate from the cusor--this isn't up to me.  If it's possible to hack up the drag-n-drop API to get it to follow the cursor, that'd work fine.  Events are closely monitored, and only being fired when absolutely necessary.  `$(window).on('mousemove', ...)` is the only relevant code attached, and it keeps processing to a simple position update, not even any calculations.  Everything is `off()`'d when no longer in use.

Comment: @Spudley I looked at the drag and drop API.  It's pretty close, but unfortunately, it only allows for an image to follow the cursor.  I need something a bit more complex, as I'm working with a sprite sheet.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, CSS does not support positioning elements relative to mouse pointer.

So if you're not satisfied with `cursor: url('pointer.cur')` (thanks @ilya-streltsyn), then JavaScript is the only solution for you.

<sub>Or maybe you shouldn't do that in the first place. When an SWF uses a custom cursor, this freaks me out a lot.</sub>

Comment: This is not completely true. Custom images as mouse cursors are allowed by both [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html) and CSS3 UI module. But there are some issues in browser support of this feature: http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/cursor.html#t017

Comment: Thank you @IlyaStreltsyn, i've updated my answer according to your correction.

Comment: This is not entirely true.  I can already think of a few ways to abuse `:hover` to position relative to the mouse cursor; they're just not elegant or realistic solutions in comparison to JavaScript.  I am aware that there is no direct support for position elements relative to the cursor in CSS; this is already stated in the question.

Comment: I made something pretty close to usable with a few competing `@keyframes` and four `div`s, but it's not quite there.